# Mongo DB is failing to fetch data from the request in Next js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, req

I have a POST request in my Nextjs app, file path is app/api/gigs/new. The request is supposed to check for data in the request body, take that data and add it to the mongo db schema, then save it to the database. When I try sending the request via thunderclient(a tool like postman), I get the following error:

"**Data has not been saved successfully: ValidationError: GigTitle: Path `GigTitle` is required., GigDesc: Path `GigDesc` is required., BasicPrice: Path `BasicPrice` is required., StandardPrice: Path `StandardPrice` is required., BasicFeatures: Path `BasicFeatures` is required., StandardFeatures: Path `StandardFeatures` is required.**".

The kind of payload that I am sending through thunder client is like this:
**{
"gigtitle": "Gigger",
"gigdesc": "Desc",
"basicprice": "20",
"basicfeatures": "Unlimited revisions",
"stdprice": "50",
"stdfeatures": "three revisions"
}**

```
        Here is my route.js file through which I am trying to send the request:
        import { connectToDB } from "../../../../lib/mongo.js";
        import Gig from "../../../../lib/models/Gigs.model.js";

        export const POST = async (req) => {
        try {
            await connectToDB();

            const {
            gigtitle,
            gigdesc,
            basicprice,
            basicfeatures,
            stdprice,
            stdfeatures,
            } = req.body;

            const gig = await new Gig({
            GigTitle: gigtitle,
            GigDesc: gigdesc,
            // GigTags: tags,
            BasicPrice: basicprice,
            BasicFeatures: basicfeatures,
            StandardPrice: stdprice,
            StandardFeatures: stdfeatures,
            });

            await gig.save();
            return new Response("Data saved successfully", { status: 200 });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return new Response(`Data has not been saved successfully: ${error}`, {
            status: 500,
            });
        }
        };


    Here is the mongo db schema: 
    import mongoose from "mongoose";

    const GigSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        GigTitle: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        GigDesc: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        GigTags: {
          type: Array,
        },
        BasicPrice: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        StandardPrice: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        BasicFeatures: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        StandardFeatures: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        Sales: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        }
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );

    const Gig = mongoose.models.Gig || mongoose.model("Gig", GigSchema);
    export default Gig;
```

What am i doing wrong here? Please someone advice.